# How do you change position relative to absolute?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/LaRWY/10/).

This question is a follow-on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495860/trying-to-change-an-images-position-and-size-at-the-same-time).

I have a button type="image" with a neat little animation when the user clicks on it.  However, in order to get the animation to work, I have to make the button position:absolute.

Q: Can I set the position:absolute when the user presses the button?  I don't know where the button is going to be on the page because it's at the bottom of a long list.

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#save',clicked)
    function clicked(myEvent) {
        myEvent.preventDefault()

        $(this).attr('src','http://www.PhillipSenn.com/GetupAGame/Inc/png/emojiTennisBallShaved.png')
        $(this).addClass('serve')
    }
})()
```

If I just change the position property, isn't it going to jump on the page?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing `$(this).css('position', 'absolute');` ?

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#save',clicked)
    function clicked(myEvent) {
        myEvent.preventDefault()

        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');

        var local = {}
        local.width = ["50px", "swing" ]
        local.height = [ "50px", "swing" ]
        local.top = "-64px"
        $(this).animate(local,"slow")
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

notes in the remarks:

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#save',clicked)
    function clicked(myEvent) {
        myEvent.preventDefault()
        
        //save buttons calculated position:
        var _ball_x = $(this).offset().left;
        var _ball_y = $(this).offset().top;
        
        //set balls position to absolute and back to its calculated position:
        $(this).css({
            "position":"absolute",
            left:_ball_x,
            top:_ball_y
        });
        $(this).attr('src','http://www.PhillipSenn.com/GetupAGame/Inc/png/emojiTennisBallShaved.png')
        $(this).addClass('serve')
    }
})()
```

Live Demo: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaRWY/12/)**</kbd>

try removing the left/top attributes from the `.css()` function and see how it jumps when positioning changes to absolute.

Comment: yep :) offset is the key

Comment: But wait.  What if the input were way down the page, I need to know the left and top depending on how far down the user has scrolled, don't I?  I think offset is for where they are on the page, not relative to the window.

Comment: Oh no wait.  You're ok.

Comment: offset takes into account scrollTop and scrollLeft of the page as well

Comment: and besides, you cant click a button thats outside of the viewport can you :)